# modem-manager-gui won't launch anymore on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04

I got a problem with Modem Manager GUI in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It was running fine for few weeks and then suddenly it didn't launch anymore. I don't have any clue why, I didn't changed any setting of it. Can anyone help me out with this one? This is the output of ******sudo modem-manager-gui******

```
    (modem-manager-gui:6269): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:57:14.869: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed
Connection manager: Network Manager >= 0.9.0
Modem manager: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0

(modem-manager-gui:6269): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:57:19.047: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault at address: 0x20
Stack trace:
1. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f2f1f610540]
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f2f1f610540]
3. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_n_children+0x1d) [0x7f2f1f68a37d]
4. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modem-manager-gui/modules/libmodcm_nm09.so(+0x3bc0) [0x7f2f1c455bc0]
5. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_connections_enum+0x6d) [0x55feed031d4d]
6. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a520) [0x55feed052520]
7. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_devices_open+0x1c0) [0x55feed036f90]
8. modem-manager-gui(+0x415d2) [0x55feed0495d2]
9. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a7a2) [0x55feed0527a2]
```